# Revert a specific transaction changes

Tags: version-control, accurev

I have the following stream structure:

```
Parent-+->Child1
       |
       +->Child2
```

There are changes that were promoted from stream `Child1` to stream `Parent` and broke build of the stream `Child2`.

I need to revert these changes only in `Child2`.

Exactly I need to do the following (Gig-style):

1. Get a diff over the transaction that broke the build (in inverted way)
2. Apply it to stream `Child2`

Locking of the `Child2` to the transaction is not a variant, because there are some changes that were done after the broken transaction was made.

Answer (score 1):

Hang a workspace off of Parent.  Right click on the Parent stream -> Show History -> Select transaction you wish to revert -> Click on Revert.  Choose the workspace you hung off the Parent stream.  Once the subtractive merge completes, hang this workspace off of Child2 -> Update workspace -> Promote changes.  You have now removed the bad transaction from the Child2 stream.